# Out of place sloped fading with fillbetween library

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

The following code generates the next plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading [name=myfading, top color=black, bottom color=black, middle color=white]
\pagecolor{blue!50!black}
\color{red}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
  width=13.2cm,
  scale only axis,
  xmin=25, xmax=75,
]

\addplot [red, no marks, name path=sup] table {
25  10
75  4
};

\addplot [red, no marks, name path=inf] table {
25  4
75  -2
};

\addplot [green!50, path fading=myfading, fading angle=-28]
  fill between [of=inf and sup, on layer=axis grid];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong fading]

It seems to me that the wrong behaviour is the result of a series of causes, each concurring with a different degree:

1. explicit setting of the `width`
2. use of the `scale only axis` option
3. explicit setting of the `fading angle`
4. use of `on grid` layer.

Any ideas about the problem and the solution?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue without having a solution at hand. However, you may be able to archieve the same output by means of a surface plot and a suitable colormap: 4 points define a rectangular surface, and 4 colordata values would define which part of the colormap is used for which point. A colormap with dark green -> light green -> dark green would result in such an output.